# MYSQL 100000 update

Tags: mysql

I everyone,

I have to update about 100000 fields in my db with a file.
So I have a file like this:

```
update db set field='truc0' where id='0'
update db set field='truc1' where id='1'
...
update db set field='trucn' where id='n'
```

I parse the file and for each line I send the request to my db

But my problem is that the process is extremly slow.
For example, I have started the process and 
2% = 2064 requests = 900seconds

Do you know another process to do the same things but in an much better time?

thx a lot for your answers

Comment: Do you want to update ALL records in the table or a subset?

Comment: Is there an index on the 'id' field? Each update would require a full table scan if not, so you'd be processing n * 100,000 rows.

Answer (score 6):

Something like this will surely go much faster because it's a single query instead of n queries:

```
update db set field='truc' + cast(id as varchar)
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question it is not exactly clear if you want to update all rows in the db or just special ids that you read from a file.

In the latter case, try to read chunks from the file and group the ids together. 
eg. if a file chunk contains the ids 3 4 5 6 7 8 you can optimize the query

```
update db set field=.... where id between 3 and 8;
```

(careful if you use varchar keys instead of integers though!)

if the ids are random you might still get a performance boost by using the sql "IN" clause

```
update db set field=... where id in ('18','49','72','30','187');
```